Redirect to login if not authenticated using Next.js middleware
i'm trying to redirect to the login page if my token is undefined however the login page is not showing i think there is a problem with my condition or my matcher
This is my function
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

  const token:string|undefined = request.cookies.get('token')?.value;
 
if (token!==undefined) {
  return NextResponse.next()
}

return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)'],
}

and this is how my login page is showing
enter image description here

your image shows
localhost redirected you too many times. 

that is because your regex matches "/login", that meaans your middleware will run when you visit login, you are kinda in an infinite loop. your regex
matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)'],

says, anthing inside here (?!api|_next|.*\\..*) should not match,

anything starts api
anything starts with _next
anything starts with .. maybe, .png, .css

but anything outside should match. so /login will stay outside and it will match so your middleware will run on "login". if you change your regex to this:
matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*|login).*)'],

your code should work.
Now you have to consider this case:

if the user is already authenticated and tries to visit the login page.

It is a good practice to redirect user to a different route, maybe the home page or a dashboard. This improves the user experience by preventing unnecessary access to the login page once they are logged in. so you should add this logic to your middleware:
const isAuthenticated = !!token;

// first, check if the current path is login page
if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login")) {
  // I am in "login" page now  I check if the user is authenticated or not
  if (isAuthenticated) {
     // If I get here it means user is on "login" page and it is authenticated. then redirect it to whatever url
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/home", req.url));
  }
 
}


thank u so much!! however when i did add the login to the matcher the page is not longer being redirected to the /dashboard page i think because the middleware is no longer working on the /login page so any logic inside of it will not work on the login page

can you remove "login" from matcher and try again

i'll try to do that thank u
